# Table cut off when using PgfplotsTable

Tags: pgfplotstable, booktabs

I'm having trouble getting the table below to indent correctly. It gets cut off as the indentation is very big. Any ideas? Any help is appreciated :)

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}

    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \usepackage{colortbl}

    \begin{filecontents*}{rawdata.dat}
    {2013 EOY} {2014 EOY} 04/15 05/15   06/15   07/15   08/15   09/15   10/15   11/15
    26.075  9.4189737 12.717323  1.8988949  7.9996209 11.5243905 10.9160107  1.389448  2.8652920  1.42878541
    11.166478 25.5374925  6.662897  2.9245013 13.5448818 12.0201447  1.2621673 19.217686  3.8883882  3.00943306
    22.315490  9.8708633 10.965354  0.8984676  1.1459839  3.8454883 15.4547797  9.402878 11.7026024  5.47339668
    11.874096  0.4823746 15.911913  6.1727927 15.1162651 34.2306360 10.3890439  2.205675  6.7049603 22.56286746
     3.320455 25.8995833  4.139036  2.2546034 12.6317242  6.8379476  8.2967574 22.880100  2.6998974  8.76554784
    10.742752  1.1641779  2.921571  3.5143500  1.7125639  2.0757867  6.2450910 15.189848  0.5610844  2.13485778
    15.162232  3.2194334  3.368766  8.5433378 15.0155505 10.7678579  2.2994006  7.680461 15.1313005  1.29770248
     3.142244  0.8621933  3.589560  1.3426351  7.6149833  0.9031139  8.3498388 10.337712 21.8489050  2.59146735
    19.911731  5.1214246  1.928850  8.3029705  6.6282564 15.6325715 24.4529297 10.528238  4.5189110  6.80297890
     7.091692 15.0789856 14.061697  2.6505780 19.6282942  3.4523669  0.4425993 14.456910 10.4345100  2.15112929
     2.943245  1.1240063  3.323045  1.1879055  0.3924865 11.9174661 12.1291137 32.115301 12.6307365  1.16558044
     3.455690 37.7236906  2.911425 22.8336110 11.2459661 21.0664441 10.5629633 26.626076 17.7553881  1.63495051
     1.543219  2.6222850 33.359461  0.3653793  0.9214781 37.7775433 25.1749934  7.062679  6.1265833 30.66471547
     3.166661 14.8145643  1.911507 21.1688017  3.7155312 28.5108371  2.8972420  9.858501 18.9646412  0.03856634
    30.285687  0.5059537 10.184070 32.2728897  5.3188059  0.8016338  2.3232517  8.902755  2.6835381  1.61584320
    \end{filecontents*}


    \begin{document}
    \setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{.75ex}

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        create on use/firstcol/.style={
        create col/set list= {\textbf{Outstanding Loan Portfolio},,\textbf{Repossessed Loan Portfolio},,\textbf{Repossession ratio eop}, \textbf{Repossession ratio},,\textbf{PAR1},,,\textbf{PAR30},,,\textbf{PAR60},}
        },
        create on use/secondcol/.style={
            create col/set list={\textbf{USD},\textbf{\#},\textbf{USD},\textbf{\#},,,\textbf{USD},\textbf{\%},\textbf{\#},\textbf{USD},\textbf{\%},\textbf{\#},\textbf{USD},\textbf{\%},\textbf{\#}}
        },
        columns/firstcol/.style={column name=,string type,column type/.add={>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}}{}},
        columns/secondcol/.style={column name=,string type,column type=r},
        columns/{2013 EOY}/.style={column name=\textbf{2013 EOY},string type,column type/.add={>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}}{}},
        columns/{2014 EOY}/.style={column name=\textbf{2014 EOY},string type,column type/.add={>{\columncolor[gray]{.9}}}{}},
        columns/{04/15}/.style={column name=\textbf{04/15}},
        columns/{05/15}/.style={column name=\textbf{05/15}},
        columns/{06/15}/.style={column name=\textbf{06/15}},
        columns/{07/15}/.style={column name=\textbf{07/15}},
        columns/{08/15}/.style={column name=\textbf{08/15}},
        columns/{09/15}/.style={column name=\textbf{09/15}},
        columns/{10/15}/.style={column name=\textbf{10/15}},
        columns/{11/15}/.style={column name=\textbf{11/15}},
        columns={firstcol,secondcol,{2013 EOY}, {2014 EOY}, 04/15,  05/15,  06/15,  07/15,  08/15,  09/15,  10/15,  11/15},
        header=true,
        every head row/.style={before row={\toprule},after row={\midrule}},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        every row no 2/.style={before row=\midrule},
        every row no 4/.style={before row=\midrule},
        every row no 6/.style={before row=\midrule},
        every row no 9/.style={before row=\midrule},
        every row no 12/.style={before row=\midrule},
        outfile=example_out.tex
    ]{rawdata.dat}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/106162)

Comment: In particular, do look into loading the `rotating` package and encasing the `\pgfplotstabletypeset[...]{...}` material inside a `sidewaystable` environment. Depending on the size of the text block, you may also need to issue a directive such as `\footnotesize` inside the `sidewaystable` environment in order to make the full table fit inside the textblock.